# Understanding curried function passed in to fold

Tags: scala, fold, monoids

I am having problems understanding [this](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/7a43335a04679e140c8c4cf7c359fd8a39bbe39f/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/monoids/Monoid.scala#L98) code from the Book FP in Scala. Here is the code:

```
trait Monoid[A] {
  def op(a1: A, a2: A): A
  def zero: A
}

def endoMonoid[A]: Monoid[A => A] = new Monoid[A => A] {
    def op(f: A => A, g: A => A) = f compose g
    val zero = (a: A) => a
}

def foldMap[A, B](as: List[A], m: Monoid[B])(f: A => B): B =
  as.foldLeft(m.zero)((b, a) => m.op(b, f(a)))

// The function type `(A, B) => B`, when curried, is `A => (B => B)`.
  // And of course, `B => B` is a monoid for any `B` (via function composition).
def foldRight[A, B](as: List[A])(z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B =
    foldMap(as, endoMonoid[B])(f.curried)(z)
```

`foldMap` is expecting a function `f: A => B`.

In `foldRight`, when `f` is curried you have `A => (B => B)`, so I suppose `f.curried` is working because it is the same as `(A => B => B)`, so `foldRight` is passing in to `foldMap` what it expect (a function with type `A => B`), then, what happends next is that `foldMap` is called and its returning a function `B => B`, and that's when `z` comes into play in `(f.curried)(z)` you call the function `B => B` with the argument `z` to get the final `B`.

Am I right? it is a litle complicated to reason about this code for me.

*NOTE:* Here is a [scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/fjxsoc5/4) if you want to play with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you seem to be mostly comprehensive to me. Nevertheless, I would clarify some points:

- I'd rather say "so I suppose **`f.curried`** is working because **`A => (B => B)`** is the same as `(A => B => B)`" (***it*** is ambiguous here and you're talking about `f.curried` result type basically, not with `z`)
- I'd rather put a point instead of a comma here:  "`foldMap` is expecting a function f: A => B **. In** foldRight, *...* " and pretty much every where else. Shorter phrases, clearer explanation.
- what *could* be an error, (and what is confusing to you?) is that `(f.curried)(z)` doesn't work on its own and is not called after `foldMap(as, endoMonoid[B])`. It's first `foldMap(as, endoMonoid[B])(f.curried)` which is called and then `(z)`. The first returns `B => B` and called with the second returns `B`.

Comment: But I clearly don't know how to explain coarsely, yet, why `B => B` can be assimilated as a `B` by calling `foldMap` this way: `foldMap(as, endoMonoid[B])(f.curried)`. I guess it's because `A => (B => B)` is a supertype of `A => B` and that `B => B` is a subtype of `B`.

If that's what is unclear to you, it'd be better to wait for someone who knows how to explain this point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have applied the edits.